# Github with netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I would like to have access to Github with netbeans. But I cant find options in the Git plugin to set the url for the Repo on Github to commit, checkout and so on. At this time, is it possible to use Netbeans to get access to github?

Comment: this question hinges on another: does the netbeans plugin have support for remotes? specifically the protocols github allows: ssh and https

Comment: @FallingBullets GitHub is not _only_ that. It also includes an **issue tracker** and a **pull requests'** interface. It will be _great_ if they could be integrated to NetBeans.

Answer (score 7):

Netbeans 7.1 Release Candiate 2 has embedded Git Supoort, without any plugins.

Comment: I've been using the git support in NB7.1 now for a while, and find it to be stable and feature-complete enough for most regular tasks. I am using it in conjunction with both public GitHub-hosted and private BitBucket-hosted git repos, as well as git repos hosted only locally on my machine.

Comment: @RobertB it works very fluently, I have also use with both GitHub and BitBucket and had no problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/issues/detail?id=41#c8) nbgit (if this is what you're using) does not support pushing/pulling from remotes. The integrated version may have remotes enabled in a future version, it's currently being specified (see [v7.0.1](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan#M5_%2814._May_2011,_planned_for_7.0.1%29))

Comment: Can you quote the part of the document that makes you think that the integrated version should have remote enabled in v. 7.0.1? I can't find it.

Comment: That link says that it has use cases for Distributed Workflow (Clone, Push, Pull, and Fetch)...Ah so they're just use cases, sorry I read that wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans v7.0.1 with the Git plugin v0.2.12.42.1 installed.
You should be able to access **public** Github repositories only.

So far I've not been able to access a **private** Github repository.

Answer (score 1):

I also have Netbeans v7.0.1 with the Git plugin v0.2.12.42.1 installed. I have been able to push and pull from both public and private repositories.

Comment: Does it need adding settings of Github? How does it go?

Answer (score 1):

For NetBeans 12, I've detailed the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66478551/1790502).

In summary: add a new Repository under Tasks, add an OAUTH token known as a Github *Personal Access Token* obtained from github.com by clicking your avatar > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token. Once you have that, the rest of the fields will populate when you click `Add Repository` and select the repo whose issues you want to integrate as tasks.