# Integration between Github Issues and Netbeans

Tags: version-control, netbeans, ide, github, development-environment

Is posible to integrate the project issue tracker of Github into Netbeans to automatize the add, change or remove issues trough the IDE.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Hehe, just found this question with a Google search. I think there is no solution yet, but I have still hope left some development will be started into this direction.

Comment: take a look at this post, it also discusses this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111467/github-with-netbeans

Answer (score 3):

It seems the current answer is no (at least I could not find anything in the mailing list or even the bug database)

Therefore I opened a corresponding report for [an enhancement](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221046). Feel free to register and vote on it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really needed to have this integration, since you can comment on or close GitHub  issues through the git comment.

Examples:

```
Reimplement feature XYZ as described in #123
Removed extra spaces in foo. Fixes #148
Working on integration with bar. #99 and octocat/bar#20
```

[Read this blog post](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation)

Answer (score 0):

This integration is available in NetBeans 12.

From the Window menu, select Tasks. In the Tasks tab, add a repository by clicking the icon on the right side of the repository header.

[image: Repository header]

A dialog appears. Select *GitHub Issues* as the Connector.

[image: Create Task Respository dialog]

You'll need an OAUTH token, known as a GitHub *Personal Access Token*. To create one, visit [github.com](https://github.com/), log into your account. Click on your account icon in the upper right corner and select `Settings` from this pulldown menu.

Now click `Developer settings` on the navigation menu on the left. Click `Personal access tokens` on the new menu on the left. Click `Generate new token`. Put a descriptive name in the Note field.

Select the appropriate permissions. Unfortunately I'm not certain what minimum permissions are required, but those I selected, which seem to work, are: `notifications`, `read:discussion`, `read:enterprise`, `read:gpg_key`, `read:public_key`, `read:user`, `repo`, `workflow`. Thanks in advance if you can provide further insight here.

Next click the `Generate token` button. You'll be presented with the token secret once and only once. Copy it and paste into the `Oauth Token` field in the NetBeans dialog from above. Click `Add repository`.

A dialog appears prompting you to select the username and repo for which you'd like to track Issues. Choose one and click `Ok`. This will populate the remaining fields in the Create Task Repository dialog. Click `Connect` to verify and you should see a success message.

[image]

Click `Ok` on the popup, and again on the dialog, and you should see your new repo and list of Issues.

[image]

And that's it. You can now open Issues, assign them, add comments, manage labels, change issues to PRs, create milestones, manage templates, and so forth.

Comment: According to https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-github-issues-plugin, the proper permission for the OAuth token is just "repo".